# Shell Find and Replace Domain in all files and its folder, sub folder

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a domain

```
https://account.oldomain.com
```

I now migrate to a new domain

```
https://account.newdomain.com
```

I wanna replace all occurance of account.olddomain.com with account.newdomain.com

How do I do it

I know I can use something like

```
sed -i 's/account.oldomain.com/account.newdomain.com/g' /hello
```

But sed: couldn't edit /hello: not a regular file

How do I replace all the files inside current directory, and its directory , sub directory of directory , as in all the files and folders of the current folder

```
with containing the text account.oldomain.com with account.newdomain.com
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
find /hello -type f|xargs sed -i 's#\(account[.]\)oldomain\([.]com\)#\1newdomain\2#g'
```

I change your `.` -> `[.]`, to match exactly `dot`, not any char.